# Bash - grep & echo only linenumbers of occurence

Tags: bash

I am struggling with only displaying an errormessage with the linenumbers.

e.g.

```
ERROR: Rule19: Tunerparams and/or CalcInternal in Script at 13, 15, 22
```

Could you please check and help me to get it right (I am very new to this)

```
checkCodingRule19()
{ 
   grep -En  "TunerParams|CalcInternal" $INPUT_FILE && 
   echo "error: ´Rule 19: Tunerparams and/or Calicinternal in Script at $line"
}
```

Comment: Replace 'grep' with 'egrep'  Grep does not understand "searchA|searchB".

Comment: Or replace `"TunerParams|CalcInternal"` with `'TunerParams\|CalcInternal'` (note the change in quotation style).  Grep treats `|` alone as an ordinary character.

Comment: @Daniel `grep` uses basic regular expression syntax, in which `|` needs to be escaped to mean _or_. `grep -E` enables extended regular expressions. [`egrep` is an obsolescent version equivalent to `grep -E`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xcu/egrep.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of `grep` you can use this simple `awk` script:

```
awk '(NR==13 || NR==15 || NR==22) && /TunerParams|CalcInternal/' file.log
```

- `NR==13 || NR==15 || NR==22` will execute this command only for line numbers 13, 15 & 22
- `/TunerParams|CalcInternal/` will search for these patterns in a line
- **Better to check for line numbers first to avoid regex search in each line.**

Answer (score 0):

```
line=`awk '$0 ~ /Tunerparams|CalcInternal/ {printf NR ", " }' < $INPUT_FILE | sed "s/, $//"`
echo "error: Rule 19: Tunerparams and/or Calicinternal in Script at $line"
```

### Technical Explanation

Use `awk` to search for Tunerparams or CalcInternal in $INPUT_FILE. Print `NR`, the line number, each time a match is made. Append a ", ". Pipe the output to `sed` to trim the last comma. `$line` now has the comma-delimited list of numbers. So simply echo it out.

I noticed there is a "´" in your echo statement which probably doesn't belong.